# Sparql query for birthplace of CEOs of S&P 500 list of companies using dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am completely new to sparql.

I want to extract the birthplace of american CEOs (the name of the State they were born in). Those CEOs should have been (currently or in the past) the CEO of companies in the list of S&P index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies). I am struggling because I don't know how to link the CEOs with companies or to filter the CEOs based on the companies they worked for. I was wondering if you could help me write a sparql query for this that works in dbpedia.

The final dataset should have several columns: CEO name, birthplace (state only), birthdate, company name (should be an S&P500 company).

Non of the queries I have written worked so decided not to put anything here and start from scratch.

Many thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 5):

The first step would be to determine the property(ies) that define the CEO of a company:

```sql
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?p
WHERE
  { ?s a dbo:Company .
    ?s ?p ?o
    FILTER regex(str(?p), "ceo", "i")
  }
```

It returns a lots of properties:

```sql
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              p                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceo                              |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceo&Founder                      |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/president&Ceo                    |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/president/ceo                    |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceo&Md                           |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/companyCeo                       |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/chairman&Ceo                     |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/georgiGanevPresident&CeoLocation |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/founder&Ceo                      |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/previousCeo                      |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/richardOwen,(ceo)Products        |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/groupPresident&Ceo               |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/owner/founderCoCeo               |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/placeOfBirth                     |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/chairmanAndCeo                   |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/currentCeo                       |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceo/cfo                          |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/founder,ceo                      |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceoType                          |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceoChengLuoKeyPeople             |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/ceo&President                    |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/placeOfDeath                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some of those could indeed be filtered out instantly, e.g. `http://dbpedia.org/property/placeOfDeath` - or you would use a better regular expression...

The most obvious candidate would be `http://dbpedia.org/property/ceo`, but we might have lower recall.

The next step is to find out properties that restrict companies to "S&P500". From the Wikipedia infobox I only see the "traded as" entry, so via SPARQL:

```sql
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?p
WHERE
  { ?s a dbo:Company .
    ?s ?p ?o
    FILTER regex(str(?p), "traded", "i")
  }
```

We get

```sql
+----------------------------------------------+
|                      p                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| http://dbpedia.org/property/tradedAs         |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/tradedUnder      |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/tradedOn         |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/formerlyTradedAs |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/traded           |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

So it might be that `http://dbpedia.org/property/tradedAs` is the way to go.

The next step? Use those properties and build the final query. And hope it returns the expected data. As a starting query:

```sql
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?s
WHERE
  { ?s a dbo:Company .
    ?s dbp:tradedAs <http://dbpedia.org/resource/S&P_500_Index>
  }
```

Comment: I still have one more problem. The final query returns the name of the companies in S&P 500 (which is what I want) but I need to have the name of CEOs of these companies and their birthplace in the final results. I tried several options but non of them seems to be working.I was wondering if you could kindly help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: I showed you that there are a lot's of candidate proeprties to get the CEOs. Did you really read my answer? It was just a starting point for the final SPARQL query. Try to add for instance the `dbp:ceo` property in another triple pattern. You will see that only 4 companies have information about the CEO via that property.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I got it. I now have the query.

Comment: @Ali can you share the final query? I get nothing with `tradedAs`, eg http://dbpedia.org/page/Zoetis doesn't have such property